# How to use accordion-group with corresponding ed_empid when it is clicked?

Tags: angular, accordion

How to use accordion-group with corresponding ed_empid when it is clicked?
**while clicking on the button it will display the employee names in accordion-group but the problem is on clicking on each of the employee name in the accordion-group first names value will be same to second accordion and while clicking second name it will show the same value to both the names.Each employee is having a unique id and there values are also unique but while clicking on accordion-group of each name the id`s are called to both the accordion-group. How to solve this problem??***

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="employeeDetails()" (click)="isCollapsed1 = !isCollapsed1"
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBasic1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Approved/Reject
        </button>
        <div id="collapseBasic1" aria-expanded="false" [collapse]="!isCollapsed1"> 
              <accordion-group *ngFor="let user of employeeName" heading = "{{user.ed_firstname}}" (click) = "todaysWeekData1(user.ed_empid)"> 
    <div [ngSwitch]="view" class="agCal">
                  <div class="cal-header taskHeader" dragoverclass="cal-drag-over" mwldroppable="" ng-reflect-klass="cal-header" ng-reflect-drag-over-class="cal-drag-over"><b>Task</b></div> 
                    <mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week" [events]=""  [weekStartsOn]="0" [viewDate]="viewDate" [refresh]="refresh" >
                    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
                  </div>
                 <div *ngIf="div4">
                  <table border='1' width='100%' class="taskTable">
                    <tr>
                      <td *ngFor="let user of reporteetimesheet"> {{ user.t_totaleffort }}</td>         
                    </tr> 
                  </table> 
                </div>
             </accordion-group> 
            </div>
```

```
todaysWeekData1(emp_id:number){
        this.condition['t_emp'] = emp_id;
        console.log("Todays Button Clicked");
        this.condition['start_date'] = this.datePipe.transform(startOfWeek(this.viewDate), "yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.condition['end_date'] = this.datePipe.transform(endOfWeek(this.viewDate), "yyyy-MM-dd");
        console.log(this.condition['start_date']);
        console.log(this.condition['end_date']);

        this.service.getPersonalTimesheet1(this.condition).subscribe((reporteetimesheet: Timesheet[]) => {
          this.reporteetimesheet = reporteetimesheet;
          console.log(this.condition['t_emp']);
          console.log(this.condition['start_date']);
          console.log(this.condition['end_date']);
          console.log(this.reporteetimesheet);
        },
        err => console.log(err));

        this.service.getTasks1(this.condition).subscribe((reporteetaskassign: Taskassign[]) => {
          this.reporteetaskassign = reporteetaskassign;
          console.log(this.condition['t_emp']);
          console.log(this.condition['start_date']);
          console.log(this.condition['end_date']);
          console.log(this.reporteetaskassign);
          console.log("today completed");
        },
        err => console.log(err));

        this.div1 = false;
        this.div2 = false;
        this.div3 = true;
        this.div4 = true;
      }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="employeeDetails()" (click)="isCollapsed1 = !isCollapsed1"
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBasic1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Approved/Reject
        </button>
        <div id="collapseBasic1" aria-expanded="false" [collapse]="!isCollapsed1"> 
              <accordion-group *ngFor="let user of employeeName" heading = "{{user.ed_firstname}}" (click) = "todaysWeekData1(user.ed_empid)"> 
    <div [ngSwitch]="view" class="agCal">
                  <div class="cal-header taskHeader" dragoverclass="cal-drag-over" mwldroppable="" ng-reflect-klass="cal-header" ng-reflect-drag-over-class="cal-drag-over"><b>Task</b></div> 
                    <mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week" [events]=""  [weekStartsOn]="0" [viewDate]="viewDate" [refresh]="refresh" >
                    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
                  </div>
                 <div *ngIf="div4">
                  <table border='1' width='100%' class="taskTable">
                    <tr>
                      <td *ngFor="let user of reporteetimesheet"> {{ user.t_totaleffort }}</td>         
                    </tr> 
                  </table> 
                </div>
             </accordion-group> 
            </div>
```